# Android Shark (tcpdump) creates invalid pcap

Tags: android, wireshark, scapy, tcpdump, packet-capture

I am for some purposes running Shark, a tcpdump tool for Android. I run this on two android devices, grab the capture files and then intend to run some stats on it. One tablet, and one phone.
They run Android 4.2.2 and 4.3 respectively. Capture for both devices is run with flags `-vv -s 0`. I have of course tried re-installing.

Looking at the data in Wireshark, the data from the phone is fine, but the data from the tablet wont be read correctly (will not identify any protocols or anything.).

I tried to use pcapfix on the file, but pcapfix says the file is fine. But I am unable to read it in scapy, dpkt (python libraries for reading network traffic, will just throw every packet into "other", being read as "Raw") or wireshark.

Anyone with a clue what I'm doing wrong, or how to fix the file?

[Capture file for phone (working)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3288883/shark_dump_phone.pcap)
[capture file for tablet (broken)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3288883/shark_dump_tablet.pcap)

Data is from mobile traffic (no wifi). The phone is on LTE/WCDMA/GSM while the tablet is on WCDMA/GSM. I am going to try and see if that causes it, but wont be until tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the commit comment in libpcap for my attempt to work around this particular ****up:

```
For various annoying reasons having to do with DHCP software, some
versions of Android give the mobile-phone-network interface an ARPHRD_ 
value of ARPHRD_ETHER, even though the packet supplied by that interface
have no link-layer header, and begin with an IP header, so that the
ARPHRD_ value should be ARPHRD_NONE.
```

This means that pcap files for those captures have the *wrong* link-layer header type.

If you have Wireshark, you have editcap; do

```
editcap -T rawip -F pcap shark_dump_tablet.pcap shark_dump_tablet_fixed.pcap
```

This will read all the packets of `shark_dump_tablet.pcap` and write them out to a new pcap file named `shark_dump_tablet_fixed.pcap`, but with a link-layer header type of "Raw IP", rather than "Ethernet", in the file's header.  You should be able to read the resulting file.

Comment: Oh that's amazing. Thank you!